# XAML does not reflect changes

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xaml

I've been writing a UI heavy program in C# with WPF. Suddenly, the changes that I'm making to my XAML code have stopped having any effect on the compiled program. I've tried re-compiling, cleaning and doing a total rebuild, and restarting, all to no avail. I don't know if this is helpful, but I can write nonsense in the XAML, and of course Intellisense goes crazy, but it still compiles and runs as though I haven't changed anything. I can even delete the entire XAML text, recompile, and it still runs as though nothing has changed. I'm presuming this is some kind of bug or setting in Visual Studio. More likely than not its super obvious and I'm completely overlooking it. Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: What kind of XAML file is it (UserControl, ResourceDictionary, etc.)? And, what is the "Build Action" for it?

Comment: It's a window, with a custom control embedded in it (changes to the control code also don't show up). The Build action is "Page". I've tried setting this to "None", and compiling, (which compiles, strangely), and then back to "Page", but that hasn't worked out either.

Comment: Incidentally, changes to the code-behind are reflected. Don't know if that helps...

Comment: Hmmm.... Can you post the content of `.csproj` file (when the settings are as they should be)? And, could it be that the `.csproj`, the xaml file or the output directory are read-only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are interested, I managed to resolve the issue by launching a new project and copying the code over. A bit of a blunt approach, but it worked. Thus, the problem must indeed have been a settings issue, as we suspected. Thanks for your efforts XAMeLi!